# not show record when table connected successfully in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $host ="localhost";
    $dbUsername ="jmpcompu_admin";
    $dbPassword = "Jmpcompu@";
    $dbname= "jmpcompu_member";
    $con = mysql_connect($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    if(!$con){
      die('not');
    }
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
    $result = mysql_query("select * from register", $con);
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ){
            echo "Database Connected Successfully !!!";

            echo $row["id"];
            echo $row["name"];
            echo $row["dob"];
            echo $row["gender"];
            echo $row["email"];
            echo $row["mobile"];
          }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It Shows:

```
Database Connected Successfully !!!Database Connected Successfully !!!Database Connected Successfully !!!Database Connected Successfully !!!Database Connected Successfully !!!Database Connected Successfully !!!
```

My table has 6 records.

Comment: You are displaying the message inside the `while` loop so it prints for every record. Is that what you are trying to ask about? Move it outside the loop.

Comment: And forget about `mysql_` functions. They are out-of-date and __insecure__.

Comment: Also `print_r($row)`, you will see that `$row` is __numerically__ indexed array.

Comment: use `mysqli` not `mysql`

Comment: and use `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) returns column *numbers*, not column *names*. Try the following instead:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     echo $row["id"];
}
```

**Depreciated**

The `mysql_fetch_row` extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_row` as comes from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

> Get a result row as an enumerated array

So, you either use 0,1,2,3 etc inexes when outputting data:

```
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
```

Or use another function - [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

But in the end - you **must** avoid `mysql_` functions, because of warning on every manual page of these functions:

> **This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.**

Consider moving to `PDO` or `mysqli` **immediately**.